# Reviews Stars Not showing on Homepage

Tags: magento2

`$product->getRatingSummary()` where this function come ?

I'm using a custom template on my magento site and I've got everything working but star ratings are not showing on the site's homepage (The one that displays latest and featured product). Its also not showing on recently seen items on side bar and also related products but it is showing on category pages and on product individual pages.

Can someone please explain what I need to do?

Appreciate your response(S). Below is the code;

Answer (score 0):

You needs to call getReviewsSummaryHtml function of following block

@var \Magento\Review\Block\View $block

```
$reviewblock =  $this->getLayout()
      ->createBlock('Magento\Review\Block\View');
$reviewblock->getReviewsSummaryHtml($block->getProductData());
```

or

@var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct

```
$reviewblock =  $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct');
$reviewblock ->getReviewsSummaryHtml($block->getProduct(), false, true);
```

you needs to pass product data or its object based on the method you use from above.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i am using magento2.3.3

Comment: how i cakk this block in magento2 phtml page

Comment: <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType, true); ?>

Comment: @dfsd
Please check I have updated the answer.